# How can I format and export data into an excel sheet in Angular

Tags: angular, excel, typescript, frontend, export-to-excel

I have data that is in the form like this

```
export const FAMILIES = {

jonesFamily: [
{
name: 'mike',
age: '46'
},
{
name: 'jill',
age: '12'
}],

smithFamily: [
{
name: 'jane',
age: '14'
},
{
name: 'igor',
age: '31'
}]
```

I want to export it into an excel sheet where the data is listed like this

```
| familyname   |    name |
------------------------------
| jonesFamily  | mike    |
| jonesFamily  | jill    |
| smithFamily  | jane    |
| smithFamily  | igor    |
```

is this possible? i am fairly new to angular, id appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: Hello! Maybe you can check this package: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs

Comment: Here is a example with Angular https://www.thecodehubs.com/export-excel-using-angular/